# Android rxJava multiple responses

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

I'm using MVVM architecture with rxjava and I'm trying to get one response from couple of queries but it doesn't do anything not even throws errors

**Query method in DAO**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE type =:type")
fun getNotes(type: String): Single<List<Note>>
```

**LocalDataSource**

```
class NotesLocalDataSource private constructor(
        private val notesDao: NotesDao
) : NotesDataSource {

    override fun getNotes(): Single<Notes> {
        return Single.zip(
                notesDao.getNotes("typeOne"),
                notesDao.getNotes("typeTwo"),
                notesDao.getNotes("typeThree"),
                notesDao.getNotes("typeFour"),
                Function4 { t1, t2, t3, t4 ->
                    Notes(t1,t2,t3, t4)
                })
    }
```

**NotesDataSource**

```
interface NotesDataSource {

    fun getNotes() : Single<Notes>

}
```

**Notes Model**

```
data class Notes(val typeOne: List<Note>, val typeTwo: List<Note>, val typeThree: List<Note>, val typeFour: List<Note>)
```

**Respository**

```
class NotesRepository(
        private val notesLocalDataSource: NotesDataSource
) : NotesDataSource {

override fun getNotes(): Single<Notes> {
        return notesLocalDataSource.getNotes()
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
notesRepository.getNotes().map {
    Log.e("TAG","Notes: $it")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `subscribe()` to that stream in order for it to start producing items.

Just call `subscribe()` function inside ViewModel or Fragment/Activity

Comment: Thank you it works now! And how about architecture I'm I using it right way? I mean this Single.zip and .map?

Comment: @kosas this is extremely basic knowledge as far as rxjava goes. It would serve you well to read documentation of any library you are using to avoid such issues in  the future

Comment: Yes, thats simple use of common operators + MVVM with Repository pattern